# import excel form into wordpress

Tags: forms, import

We have an order form made with excel that we share with clients, they usually download, fill the form (only the quantity column needed) and send it back to us.

We would like for clients to be able to fill and submit this online.

Is there any way to convert this excel file into an online form?
I know i could embed the excel file however i am hopping there's a way to import the excel Row data into a form plugin (gravity form for example).

The reason I am looking for an import solution is that the excel form contains +-200 rows of items and therefore it is cumbersome to recreate the form by hand.

Looking forward to suggestions
Thank you

Comment: If you can write some code to make dynamic forms from CSV data with a simple foreach loop (I never seen your Excel file, just thought it'd be simple with description and quantity fields), then it's easy to make a CSV file from a spreadsheet. There are [plenty of tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=csv+import+to+wordpress) on this. I've a [detailed one](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/csv-bengali-import-using-php-mysql/) especially for Bengali readers.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think you'd be better off just doing it manually. ~200 rows of items isn't really that much, relatively. And even if you did find a way to import the excel file to make a form out of it, you'd still need to edit most of the data fields anyway. I highly doubt you'd really save that much time.

In other words: Sometimes you just have to do it the hard way. ;)